# Batch checking for internet connection or connect to WLAN

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have written this batch file.
The reason for this is that my co-workers forget to connect WLAN before starting a batch installation. It happened that the file gets bugged and frees. If I restart it its okay again.

Maybe there is a better way to write it?

**wlancheck.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Sjekker maskin for nettverk. 
REM Maskin pinger www.vg.no
:wlancheck
ECHO ****************************************
ECHO *****SJEKKER OM MASKIN ER P† NETT!*******
ECHO ****************************************
ping www.vg.no>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto nonet
if errorlevel 0 goto gotnet

:nonet 
CLS
color cf
ECHO ****************************************
ECHO ******        IKKE P† NETT!!!    *******
ECHO ******     SCRIPT G†R I LOOP     *******
ECHO ******    TIL MASKIN ER P†NETT  *******
ECHO ****************************************
timeout /t 10
REM Setter wlanprofil
CLS
ECHO ****************************************
ECHO *****   Setter WLAN INSTILLINGER   *****
ECHO ****************************************
START /wait /min %~d0\bat\setup\addwlanprofile.bat
timeout 10 >nul
CLS
Goto wlancheck
:gotnet
CLS
color a0
ECHO ****************************************
ECHO *****     MASKIN ER P† NETT!     *******
ECHO ****************************************
timeout 4 >nul
CLS
Exit
```

**addwlanprofile.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
netsh wlan add profile filename=%~d0\reg\wlan.xml
exit
```

Comment: This would work a lot better in vbscript. I will make you one if interested.

Comment: I would be glad if you did. But is there a way to get it "animated" in vbs? It's not necessary do.

Comment: VBScript does not support animation that I am aware of.

Comment: We have to be careful about not setting a precedent that SO is a free code writing service. I only had time to do this because I am laid up on the couch after surgery. I will not be creating anymore scripts from scratch for any other members. Hopefully I won’t get beat up to bad over it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This replaces both batch files. The script will make 4 additional attempts after adding the .xml and doing the first ping to the server before throwing a message. You can temporarily “unremark” line 20 for debugging to make sure your paths are correct for the .xml import. You can put a bogus server name at the top of the script to see what happens on error. Let me know if you need any more assistance. I created this for you in the hopes that you will see how cool scripting is and want to give it a try. I’m sure people will say you should learn Powershell instead. I would love to see someone replicate this in Powershell. The ping code snippets were used from this site. 
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_network_ping.php  You need to call the script using %windir%\System32\wscript.exe WlanCheck.vbs

```
strSite = "www.vg.no"

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strWinDir = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
strWorkingDir = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")

If Ping(strSite) = "True" Then
  MsgBox "CONNECTED", 64, "NETWORK STATUS"
  WScript.Quit
End If
Do While Ping(strSite) = "False"
  ReturnValue = MsgBox("NOT CONNECTED" & vbCrLf & "CONNECT NOW?", 20, "NETWORK STATUS")
    If ReturnValue = 6 Then
      Count = Count + 1
        If Count > 5 Then
          MsgBox "UNABLE TO CONNECT TO NETWORK" & vbCrLf & "CONTACT SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR", 0, "NETWORK STATUS"
          WScript.Quit
        Else
          If Not Count > 1 Then
            'WScript.Echo strWinDir & "\System32\cmd.exe /C " & strWinDir & "\System32\netsh.exe wlan add profile filename=" & strWorkingDir & "reg\wlan.xml"
            WshShell.Run(strWinDir & "\System32\cmd.exe /C " & strWinDir & "\System32\netsh.exe wlan add profile filename=" & strWorkingDir & "reg\wlan.xml"),0, True
            WScript.Sleep(10000)
          End If
        End If
    Else
      WScript.Quit
    End if
Loop

Function Ping(myHostName)
Dim colPingResults, objPingResult, strQuery
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & myHostName & "'"
Set colPingResults = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}!\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery(strQuery)
For Each objPingResult In colPingResults
  If Not IsObject(objPingResult) Then
    Ping = False
  ElseIf objPingResult.StatusCode = 0 Then
    Ping = True
  Else
    Ping = False
  End If
Next
Set colPingResults = Nothing
End Function
```